# Unexpected "uncaught" exception passed to `onError` of `runZonedGuarded()` despite `try`/`catch`

Tags: flutter, dart

Given the following complete minimal example run on Flutter 3.7.3 and Dart 2.19.2:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runZonedGuarded(() {
    runApp(const MyApp());
  }, (error, stack) {
    print('onError: $error\n$stack');
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override Widget build(BuildContext context) => const MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage());
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});
  @override State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final http.Client _httpClient = http.Client();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    request().then((value) => print('then')).catchError((error) => print('catchError'));
  }

  Future<void> request() async {
    try {
      var request = http.Request('POST', Uri.parse('http://192.168.0.1'));
      await _httpClient.send(request);
    }
    catch (error) {
      print('catch: $error');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Push the button'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _httpClient.close(), // this leads to the exceptions
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When the "+" button on the UI is pressed, a `SocketException` is both passed to the `onError` callback of the `runZonedGuarded()` and also the `catch` block of the HTTP request.

The console output is:

```
Restarted application in 720ms.
flutter: onError: SocketException: Connection attempt cancelled, host: 192.168.0.1, port: 80
#0      _NativeSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:694:35)
#1      _RawSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1855:26)
#2      RawSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:27:23)
#3      Socket._startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:2078:22)
#4      Socket.startConnect (dart:io/socket.dart:763:21)
#5      _ConnectionTarget.connect (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2466:20)
#6      _HttpClient._getConnection.connect (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2906:12)
#7      _HttpClient._getConnection (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2911:12)
#8      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2766:12)
#9      _HttpClient.openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2604:7)
#10     IOClient.send
#11     _MyHomePageState.request
#12     _MyHomePageState.initState
#13     StatefulElement._firstBuild
#14     ComponentElement.mount
--- 8< ---
#384    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3953:16)<…>
flutter: catch: Connection attempt cancelled, host: 192.168.0.1, port: 80
flutter: then
```

What I would like to know is...

1. Why are two apparently identical exceptions raised rather than one? (The two exception objects have different identity hash codes, but otherwise appear equivalent.)
2. Why, if the exception passed to `onError` is considered uncaught, does the stack trace for that very exception clearly show the `try`/`catch` block as an ancestor?
3. How can I catch the uncaught exception? So that it can be dealt with and not be uncaught?

Note: It's intentional for this demonstration that the HTTP request and subsequent client closure results in a `SocketException`. I'm not asking why this results in a `SocketException`. I'm asking why there are *two* exceptions, one of which is considered uncaught, despite the use of `try`/`catch`.

Note 2: Run on iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred because

> The Flutter framework expects that the binding initialization and the call to `runApp` will happen in the same zone. If binding initialization happens in a different zone, then callbacks set up by the binding will be associated with that zone. Exceptions thrown within those callbacks could then be dispatched to that zone's uncaught exception handler, causing the results above.

Reference: [Flutter issue #121439](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/121439).

See also [Flutter issue #94123](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94123).